# Which function in "nestjs/swagger" converts DTOs to Swagger model definitions?

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, swagger, nestjs

I have DTOs specified with [Class-Validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) and I am looking for a library that can be used to generate Swagger specification from it. I am not using it for a REST API, the code is addressing an IoT/MQTT scenario - I simply use Class-Validator to manage JSON.

[NestJS/Swagger](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger) is the best maintained library. I would like to use it's capability to produce Swagger definitions without a NestJS Server. Ideally I would like to pass in a DTO definition and get it's Swagger schema.

I have been reading the source, but am struggling to understand which function in the framework actually does that. At best, I have been able to track it down to [`modelsDefinitions` property in `swagger-explorer` class](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/master/lib/swagger-explorer.ts).

As best I can tell, from there, [`api-parameters.explorer`](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/master/lib/explorers/api-parameters.explorer.ts) and [`api-produces.explorer`](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/master/lib/explorers/api-produces.explorer.ts). The way they work is not clear to me. I was wondering of someone might help me out?

I'd like to add that I am aware of [`class-validator-jsonschema`](https://github.com/epiphone/class-validator-jsonschema), but it is not maintained and no longer seems to work properly.

Comment: The main module which is exported from index.ts seems to be https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/master/lib/swagger-module.ts , it seems to use libraries such as fastify-swagger and swagger-ui-express as well as a bunch of custom code. Did you have a chance to review that code and how it works with a standard nest project?

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to trace which code is called by swagger-module, and got stuck at the point outlines above. I think Swagger ui and fastify are not relevant to building the model.

Answer (score 1):

`nestjs/swagger` does not expose what you need as its public API which you cannot access it. The class you're looking for is `SchemaObjectFactory` and the method is `exploreModelSchema`.

Reference:

- [SwaggerObjectFactory](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/master/lib/services/schema-object-factory.ts#L76)
- [Test](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/master/test/services/schema-object-factory.spec.ts#L23)